# Why does this code leak under ARC? (A __weak instance variable)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm facing a weird leak. Objects of the following `Car` class never get deallocated.

However, if I get rid of the instance variable `_unsafe_self` and instead declare (and assign to as before) the variable within the `init` method, the leak goes away.

What could be causing this? I thought `__weak` was always weak, whether it be an instance variable or not.

```
@interface Car : NSObject
@end

@implementation Car {
  id _obs;
  __weak Car *_unsafe_self;
}

- (id)init {
  if (!(self = [super init]))
    return nil;

  _unsafe_self = self;

  _obs = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
          addObserverForName:NSWindowDidMoveNotification
          object:nil
          queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
          usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
              NSLog(@"hello %@", _unsafe_self);
            }];

  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:_obs];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_unsafe_self` is the same as `self->_unsafe_self`, therefore the block in

```
_obs = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
          addObserverForName:NSWindowDidMoveNotification
          object:nil
          queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
          usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
              NSLog(@"hello %@", _unsafe_self);
            }];
```

captures `self`, causing a retain cycle that prevents `self` from being deallocated.

This does not cause a retain cycle:

```
__weak Car *weakSelf = self;
_obs = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserverForName:NSWindowDidMoveNotification
        object:nil
        queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
        usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
            NSLog(@"hello %@", weakSelf);
        }];
```

---

Using a property `self.unsafe_self` would make this more obvious in the code, but there are already more than enough "property vs ivar" Q&As :-)